# Facebook Application to test the "sharing" feature

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share some contents on Facebook using Facebook SDK on an Android application.

I would not to create a new Facebook application because the process is very long...I have to provide logo, icons, screenshots, Privacy Policy URL,...

Is it possible to test this feature in another way?

Comment: You don't need to complete all the fields to create an application. You can get away with just completing the app name and android app settings.

Comment: Thanks! I have already tried this but I need the "publish_actions" permission and it's not enabled by default.

Comment: If you use the Share dialog from the Android SDK, you do not need to ask for the `publish_actions` permission.

Comment: In FB documentation for Android Share, cap. "Prerequisites" we can read this:
"A Facebook app properly configured and linked to your Android app, with Facebook Login enabled": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/